# Questions and Answer that requires root and registry changes will be accepted?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we allow questions that belong to a gray area?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-we-allow-questions-that-belong-to-a-gray-area)

Something like "How to take screen shot" and "How to change ringtones" have default answer to "Not currently possible".

But with root, custom ROM etc can achieve this goal.

We will accept questions and answers using techniques like root and custom ROM?